# I want to add java option line in file using sed command in shell scripting after the match

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, scripting

Hi want add below line using sed command in shell but it is not copy as same as line below

```
JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.debug.DebugSecuritySSL=true -Dweblogic.debug.DebugSSL=true -Dweblogic.StdoutDebugEnabled=true  -Dweblogic.log.StdoutSeverityLevel=Debug -Dweblogic.log.LogSeverity=Debug"
```

It skip `"${JAVA_OPTIONS} and "`

I try to use `sed`:

```
var="JAVA_OPTIONS="${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dweblogic.debug.DebugSecuritySSL=true -Dweblogic.debug.DebugSSL=true -Dweblogic.StdoutDebugEnabled=true  -Dweblogic.log.StdoutSeverityLevel=Debug -Dweblogic.log.LogSeverity=Debug""
sed -i "/minimumprotocol=/a \
$var" file.txt
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What `sed` commands have you tried? We're much more here to help with specific questions of the form "I tried X, but it did not do what I expect and instead resulted in an error!" accompanied by a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Update the command

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should escape the `$`:

```
var="JAVA_OPTIONS=\${JAVA_OPTIONS} -Dwe..."
```

Comment: It is also skipping " " at end and middle of the line

Comment: Thanks so much i got it